# How to hide new task button in home page of an user of a specific profile?

Tags: profile, user

I want to hide 'New Task' button in home page of user of a specific profile.Please suggest.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Should the user generally be able to create tasks?

Comment: No I have already restricted the task object and the user has only read only access.Anyways user will not be able to create task.But I dont want 'New task' button in home page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the "Edit Tasks" permission from his profile. This will remove the "New" button. A side-effect will be that he can't update or delete tasks either.

Note that you can't edit object level permissions for Activities (Events and Tasks), such as "Create", "Edit", or "Delete". Access is via the "Edit Tasks" and "Edit Events" user permissions.

More info:
http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181309&language=en_US

Comment: I have removed "Edit Task" permission from the profile.Also the "Create", "Edit", or "Delete" acess.Only the "read only" acess will be provided to the user.But I dont want the "New task" button in the home page which is still coming.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your own Visualforce page that just displays the list of tasks without exposing the new button.
2. Create a HomePage component of type HTML Area and then embed the above Visualforce page in an iframe.
3. Create a new Home Page Layout and add the Home Page component to it.
4. Use the Home Page Layout Assignment to assign the page to the users profile.